# How to a 5 tier nested join in SQL

Tags: sql, join, nested

I am very new to SQL.  My situation is that I need to perform a sum over all elements in the val column of the A data frame, where each element in the A data frame has an id V that is associated with a group id Y in the E data frame.  The column V is linked to the column E by id's that can be connected using JOIN across 5 tables.  Schematically, the operation that I am trying to perform is:

```
(psuedocode)
A.V join with B.V
B.W join with C.W
C.X join with D.X
D.Y join with E.Y
sum all A.val grouped by id E.Y
```

So far, I am stuck getting all the joins to work. My SQL statement for the first two joins is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM A
    INNER JOIN B
    ON (A.V= B.V) AS output1)
INNER JOIN C
ON (output1.W = C.W);
```

I am getting an error message that something is wrong near the AS clause, can someone with some experience in this sort of thing point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
Select E.Y, Sum(A.Val) SumOfVal
From A join B on A.V = B.V
       join C on B.W = C.W
       join D on C.X = D.X
       join E on D.Y = E.Y
Group by E.Y
```

If you need to bring `Id` in the result set, add it to the `group by` clause as well.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer a basic question.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all database engines allow you to do the join very similar to the way you describe it:

```
select id, E.Y, sum(A.val)
from A join
     B
     on A.V = B.V join
     C
     on B.W = C.W join
     D
     on C.X = D.X join
     E
     on D.Y = E.Y
grouped by id, E.Y;
```

Your SQL skills seem to be a bit weak.  I would recommend that you study up a bit on SQL syntax, using either books or online resources.

Comment: This is very true!  Unfortunately I am also up against deadlines.  I am sorry to waste peoples time with basic questions, the best I can do in return is promise to pay it forward at some point.